# My friend’s pepper plant has some odd leaf lesions

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, vegetables, diseases, peppers

It looks like the leaves are being distorted by whatever these lesions are. Any ideas? Viral disease? [image][image][image]

Answer (score 2):

The third photo shows distinctive leaf puckering which indicates that some creature injected something into the leaf and caused a chemical reaction. It looks rather as if some caterpillar crawled up onto the underside hoping to attach itself and spin a coccoon, but found the sap in the leaf rather hot. Plants have defensive mechanisms to discourage free riders and it looks like the rider found the ride too bumpy and moved on. MIght want to examine the soil surface for evidence, or expand the search area to see if it found another perch.

A virus would show more generalized evidence over more of the plant; the plant looks good and healthy and soon the leaf will be gone and no longer a concern.

Comment: The lesion is the shape of a caterpillar, too! Head and all. Look carefully at the second picture.